# Assigning a function a name in an if statement in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python and am extremely confused. If anyone could help me assign the rectangle created by this to the name "Obj3", that would be extremely helpful(you can see this below).

```
if event.char == "c": canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + 100, y + 50)
```

Here is my program code: -

```
app = tk.Tk()
app.title("VAB")
app.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\shafa\OneDrive\Documents\VAB\Sprites\VAB-Icon.ico")
w, h =1200, 800
x, y = w//2, h//2


canvas = tk.Canvas(app, width = w, height = h)
canvas.pack()
Obj1 = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + 100, y + 200)
points = [650, 400, 600, 330, 550, 400]
Obj2 = canvas.create_polygon(points, fill='', width = 1, outline = 'black')

def creation(event):
    if event.char == "c": canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + 100, y + 50) = Obj3

app.bind("<Key>", keyinput)
app.mainloop()
```

From this code, assigning the event created rectangle Obj3 by adding = Obj3 just doesnt work and leads to an error. I want to assign it a name without that error happening. Thank you for reading this.

Comment: It's the opposite order, as you can see in both previous examples in your code: `obj3 = canvas.create_rectangle(....)`

Comment: Assignment syntax is `variablename = value`; you seem to be trying the opposite with `value = variablename`. But there are other reasons why this won't work, a variable assigned inside a `def` is not accessible outside it. (You can make it `global` but that's usually also a bad idea; globals tend to lead to spaghetti code very quickly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is backwards, and in order to assign out of scope, you need a `global` declaration.

```py
def creation(event):
    global Obj3
    if event.char == "c": Obj3  = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + 100, y + 50)
```

Globals in general are not a recommended way to do things though. You get spaghetti code and its hard to support multithreading. Better to keep references local or encapsulate in a class.